# how to add two-line in v-btn Vuetify

Tags: vuetify.js

I'm trying to add second line to v-btn text in Vuetify:

```html
<v-btn>
    <span class="first-line">hello</span>
    <span class="second-line">world</span>
</v-btn>
```

but, it's doesn't work and show in one line!
please help me.

Comment: Do you get your answer?

Answer (score 1):

Two line text on buttons are against Material Design (basis of Vuetify) principles as they reduce legibility. Material Design documentation can be found [here](https://material.io/components/buttons#anatomy) - scroll to subheader "Text Label".

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<br />` tag as i show below:

```html
<v-btn>
    <span class="first-line">hello</span><br />
    <span class="second-line">world</span>
</v-btn>
```